# How can I take admin/insertShoutBox in action="admin/insertShoutBox" with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change action="admin/insertShoutBox" to action="" with jquery.

Can anyone tell me how to please?

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="homeright"  class="adminhome">
    <form method="post" id="form" action="admin/insertShoutBox" >

        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id;?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="user" id="nick" value="<?php echo $username;?>" />

        <p class="messagelabel"><label class="messagelabel">Message</label>
        <textarea  id="message" name="message" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>

        <input id="send" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></p>


    </form>
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [attr method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) on the form:

```
$('form#form').attr('action', '');
```